# What would be an appropriate phrase to describe how much of a movie already elapsed?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrase-request, phrases, sentence-choice

I was watching a movie on my computer and I had to go the bathroom and then my phone rang so I picked it up and talk to a caller. I was unaware I didn't pause the movie on the computer and it turned out that I talked much longer than I tough because when I came back the movie was almost in the middle of its playtime.

I described this in my head in my native language (which is Polish). Verbatim translation would be something like:

> Oh look how much of the movie already **went by**.

Is this a correct phrase describing the fact of how much playtime already happened? or how much of it already elapsed? What would be the most natural way to describe it?

Comment: Depends on your aims. Are you looking for how to describe that situation naturally, or are you interested in a appropriate phrase in the place of "went by"? I ask because to describe that situation, my first choices wouldn't use that phrasing.

Comment: I just want to know what I can say to a person e.g my girlfriend, if we went to the kitchen and also forgot to pause the movie. What would you say to her in place of " Ohh look how much movie already went by"

Comment: "Went by" is a pretty decent choice. I might say "Look how much of the movie's already played."

Comment: Incidentally, _playing time_ would be a better expression. _Playtime_ is a time for children to play.

Comment: I knew it was ringing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say either:

> Look how much of the movie *has already **gone by/played**.*

or

> "Look how much of the movie **went by/played** *while I was away*".

Note that I use *present perfect* when I don't mention the past time, but I used *simple past* when I do.

"Elapsed" is correct, but too formal for talking to your girlfriend.